# Reduce ipa file size

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, linker, ios-frameworks

Lets say I have 3rd part universal(contains symbols for both iPhone and Simulator) iOS framework: A.framewwork.

How Can I reduce final ipa file(for physical device) by removing unnecessary Simulator symbols from framework? Is XCode have such settings for linker?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're linking statically to the framework it won't put other architecture symbols into the resulting binary (e.g. the simulator architectures). If you're dynamically linking, you can use lipo to remove the other architectures from the framework as part of the copy stage

Comment: Thanks @Petesh, I have missed -remove option of lipo command! Thanks for this solution, this was answer on my question!

Answer (score 0):

Ask third party vender to get only amrv7s/armv_64 framework